# Django + Babel + Webpack unexpected token

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I'm trying to follow [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mx3ChaYA0Gw) but I'm running into this error:

```
ERROR in ./src/index.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (5:4)
```

I followed everything in the video but I don't see where I'm going wrong.

Webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: './src/index.js'
    },
    watch: true,
    devtool: 'source-map',
    output: {
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname,'dist')
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: ['babel-loader']
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [
            '.js'
        ]

    }
}
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
    <div>
        <h1>Test</h1>
    </div>,
    document.getElementById("root")
)
```

Comment: have you added the babel react plugin?

Comment: I did `npm install -D @babel/core @babel/preset-env @babel/preset-react babel-loader css-loader node-sass webpack webpack-cli`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSX syntax has to be compiled with Babel before you can load it in the browser.

To do this you can add a `.babelrc` file to the root of the project:

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
}
```

[Babel Preset React](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-react)